# CSS Typing Animation Does Not Work With Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I incorporated Bootstrap on my site to make it responsive. I also added in CSS animation to my code. However, this takes the text from being in the center of the page, to starting on the far left of the page, finishing the animation, and then shifting the text to the center.

How do I start the animation in the center itself?

Bootstrap Code:

```
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">

        <h1 class="typing">Hi, welcome to my website.</h1>
        <h3 class="typing">Let's get started.</h3>
        <br>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Get Started.</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS Code:

```
.css-typing
{
    width: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 3s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 3s steps(50, end)1;
}

@keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type{
    from { width: 0;  }
}
```

Any thoughts or help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any `keyframe` code?

Comment: Is that your full code?

Comment: I added in a key frame code. It shows the animation now, but the typing starts at the left of the screen and the text then shifts to the center of the screen after. How would I start the animation at the center of the screen, where the text already is?